# Select entry with only one entry in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Say I have a database table `user_provider`, that contains many to many relationship of `user` and `provider` table.
I want to get only those `userId` which is having only one provider

```
 SELECT spr1.SU_URS_ID,count(spr1.SU_URS_ID)
 FROM overstappen.spr_usr spr1 
 WHERE spr1.SU_URS_ID in ( select spr.SU_URS_ID 
                           from overstappen.spr_usr spr 
                           where spr.SU_SPR_ID =40) 
 GROUP BY spr1.SU_URS_ID;
```

Above query returns all users which is having `SU_SPR_ID 40`. And the total no of users with same userId in spr_usr table.

I only want to get user with `count 1`. i.e user with only one provider.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT   spr1.SU_URS_ID, COUNT(spr1.SU_URS_ID)
FROM     overstappen.spr_usr spr1 
WHERE    spr1.SU_URS_ID IN 
         (SELECT   spr.SU_URS_ID 
         FROM     overstappen.spr_usr spr WHERE spr.SU_SPR_ID =40) 
GROUP BY spr1.SU_URS_ID
HAVING   COUNT(spr1.SU_URS_ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding at the end of your query HAVING COUNT(spr1.SU_URS_ID) = 1:

```
SELECT  spr1.SU_URS_ID,count(spr1.SU_URS_ID) 
FROM    overstappen.spr_usr spr1 
WHERE   spr1.SU_URS_ID in ( 
            SELECT  spr.SU_URS_ID 
            FROM    overstappen.spr_usr spr 
            WHERE   spr.SU_SPR_ID =40) 
GROUP BY spr1.SU_URS_ID
HAVING COUNT(spr1.SU_URS_ID) = 1;
```